# Menu with collapsable submenus on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make menu with collapsable submenus.. I'm very new to jQuery) My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#list> li > ul')
    .hide()
    .click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#list> li').toggle(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
    });
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>

<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">SUBMENU1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">M11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">M12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">M13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">M14</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SUBMENU2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">M21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">M22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">M23</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">M24</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It works fine now, but I want all opened submenus to be closed automatically when I click on another submenu.. So there will be only one opened submenu at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#list> li > ul')
.hide()
.click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#list> li').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('ul').is(':visible'))
    {
       $(this).find('ul').slideUp() 
    }
    else
    {
    $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp()
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    }
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/11/)

Comment: Thank you! Almost what I need.. But when I click on "SUBMENU2" - it openes, and then I click on "SUBMENU1" - its opening only after second click..

Comment: @rustemk i updated fiddle and code as per your need if it helps accept as answer

Comment: I want to close all submenus by clicking on the last opened submenu.. For now its not closing..)

Comment: @rustemk  i updated again my fiddle and code as per your need if it helps accept as answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#list > li').siblings().find('ul').hide();
$('#list > li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp();
    $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2QKe9/

**Updated Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/2QKe9/2/

Comment: Thank you! Almost what I need, I want to close all submenus by clicking on the last opened submenu.. 
My fault, I incorrectly described the essence of the issue..)

Comment: @rustemk, You are welcome. Glad to help you. I have added updated demo in my answer. Please check.